# Observable array of observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm creating multiple dropdowns based on the number of elements inside an observable array.

This observable array is made up of observables so that, when different options within these dropdowns are selected, my observable array updates.

This "observable array of observables" trick doesn't work when the observables are passed in like this:

```
self.arrayOfObservables([ko.observable("test1"), ko.observable("test2"), ko.observable("test3")]);
```

I had to write a wrapper function to return the observables within an object:

```
function makeAnObservable(initialValue) {
    var observable = ko.observable(initialValue);
    return { observable: observable };
}
```

Now, making an observable array of observables looks like this:

```
self.arrayOfObservables([makeAnObservable("test1"), makeAnObservable("test2"), makeAnObservable("test3")]);
```

Here are two jsFiddles for clarification (one using the makeAnObservable hack and the other using ko.observable)

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/noahyonack/56WrK/6/)

[Not Working](http://jsfiddle.net/noahyonack/9Z8AX/7/)

Where am I mistaken? Why does using makeAnObservable work but ko.observable doesn't? Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/DVXH7/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand how this helps. Why does passing in observables into an observable array not work, but passing them in as objects containing observable arrays does?

Comment: an observable is an obj, as you can see in the example the example is a obj, in yours  ko.observable("test1") is not a observable where is it's name declared? your just passing data in there

Comment: You need to use `$rawData` instead of `$data` when you have observables inside an array: http://jsfiddle.net/d38YZ/ see also in the linked question.

Comment: Thanks, nemesv. That's exactly right.